# What is the difference between a REST API and an API gateway?

Tags: api-gateway, rest

I understand as REST API as a server that listens to endpoints that are filtered by HTTP verbs like POST, GET, DELETE, etc. Googling for differences didn't return useful resources. But I read that an API Gateway is used with microservices. Are these things actually the same, or maybe one is a subset of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am writing this response based on the architectures for few projects those I have seen and worked on too.

In microservices, API Gateway is the first layer that an HTTP request goes through and tasks of decoding the JWT token, then finding the user privileges, then checking for the incoming route/URI and to which backend service it shall connect to, is done using API Gateway.

It carries info about all other services those are supposed to do a work.

Let's say -

[www.xyz.com/api/{route}](http://www.xyz.com/api/%7Broute%7D) is the URL that takes call to API Gateway and at API Gateway layer this {route} is then mapped to a serivce , like if info about a product has to be obtained then this will route the URI to that.

Also it leverages us to keep those services free from any additional security layers, just API Gateway will take care of all those security related things and backend services will do the job for those they are made.

And this is all being done via API calls, written using REST , built over HTTP.

I hope this answers your question to some extent.

Comment: So based in what I read and your answer, an API gateway seems to be just a REST API on steroids that orchestrates the access to other simple APIs.

Comment: I hope u found it useful

Answer (score 0):

Well to clearly understand an API gateway, I think we can understand how it came about and why it is important.
So before the advent of APIs, applications were mainly built using the monolith approach where all software components were interconnected. But as enterprise-level systems adopt microservices and APIs, multiple issues like security and load balancing arise.

These issues can be solved by introducing an API Gateway which is an intermediate level between a client and an API.
This is an overview of what is an API Gateway but this article dives deep into discussing what an API gateway is and why it is essential in a cloud-native era.

https://api7.ai/blog/what-is-an-api-gateway/